# Unable to connect postgres server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

When I try to connect server to create database. I am getting this error.

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "host"=>"localhost", "socket"=>"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432", "pool"=>5, "min_messages"=>"error", "database"=>"rails_contributors_test"}
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried a lot but didn't get success. Looking for help.

Postgres version I have as

```
which postgres
=> /usr/local/bin/postgres
postgres --version
=> postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4
```

Comment: You need to answer the question in the error message. Have you started the server? Installing it isn't enough. On my mac, the command is `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`. But I'm running 9.4.1 at the moment, and the database path can vary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try installing [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) on your Mac OSX.

and start the postgres i.e. click on `Open psql`.

Then, restart the rails server.

After this, it should fix your issue.

#### Update (If the above does not work)

- To fix the issue, remove the `PID` file. Find the postgres data directory. On Mac OSX using homebrew it is `/usr/local/var/postgres/`.
- To make sure this is the problem, look at the log file (`server.log`). On the last lines you will see: `FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
  HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 347) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?`
- If so, `rm postmaster.pid`
- Restart your server. On Mac OSX, do:

  `launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
  `launchctl load -w homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`